# What can we derive from an experimental plot of prime gap counts?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

The below chart shows the counts of prime gaps in the number range up to $5\times10^8$.

It is clearly an interesting shape and some key features are:

- an approximate linear relationship between the log of the gap count and the gap value.
- an approximate lower bound
- an approximate upper bound
- a "thin tail" at the bottom right indicating rare large gaps
- the exception of 1 count of gap=1 (can be ignored?)

The shape seems to hold for very large number ranges, and sources/charts can be found on the internet fairly easily - eg [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMsTXQYgbiQ).

**Question:** What can we derive from these features of the experimental evidence?

**Note:** I know experimental evidence is not proof. However, experimental evidence can hint and point us towards provable insights which we might not have otherwise explored.

In particular, if anyone can explain a link between this shape and the prime number theorem would be useful. The PNT suggests the average prime gap at $x$ is $\log(x)$ but I can't seem connect that with the chart.

---

I would appreciate replies suitable for an audience not trained to university level  mathematics.

(The chart incorrectly uses the phrase "frequency" when it should say count).

[image]

Comment: It's believed (but not unconditionally proved) that the gaps between primes follow a Poisson distribution. There are also secondary effects from congruence considerations, of the type found in the leading coefficient for the conjectured asymptotic formulas for prime pairs (Hardy–Littlewood).

Comment: I just realised the "area under the line" is the prime count function $\pi(x)$ because the sum of the number of gaps $\#g$ is approx equivalent to the sum of the number of primes, and where $x$ is the sum of all the gaps $g$. However I can't seem to produce anything useful from the algebra around this.

Comment: Additional question - is it true to say that currently there is no proof that explains the shape of the distribution?

Comment: @Tariq It is true. All patterns that have been found so far (like Ulam's spiral) vanish , if the primes get larger. I remember a good statement : "large primes are different". We do not know for a single even number whether infinite many prime gaps with this size exist although this is strongly conjectured. The best result strictly proven is that infinite many prime gaps do not exceed $246$, impressing enough.

Comment: The prime number theorem allows us to study the distribution of primes very detailed. However, if it comes to concrete primes, the current knowledge is extremely limited. Many open famous problems are related to concrete prime numbers. We do not even have an efficient method to produce any (really any) new huge prime number.